# Restore the edit text value entered

Tags: android, android-edittext

The value is entered in edit text in Activity A. When going to another activity B without saving and coming back A , the value of form in edit text in Activity A gets cleared. How can the edit text value gets restored?

```
 @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    outState.putString("company", company.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("name", name.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("email",email.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("phone",phone.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("address",address.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("desc",desc.getText().toString());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
     co = savedInstanceState.getString("comoany");
     em = savedInstanceState.getString("email");
     ph = savedInstanceState.getString("phone");
     add = savedInstanceState.getString("address");
     na = savedInstanceState.getString("name");
     de = savedInstanceState.getString("desc");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    Log.i("this", "Company::::::::::::" + co);
    company.setText(co);
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: Use save instance state or shared preferences to save the value and populate it in onResume

Comment: Check this: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states

Comment: can you please explain with code? @AshishKumar

Comment: Post your code of `startActivity()`.

Comment: I have edited the question@Khemraj

Comment: use shared preference to store values of edit text and try to fetch the data from shared preference if present when activity opens

Comment: if you check the spelling of your company is wrong try correcting the typo. your key is company but in youronRestore you are calling comoany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is to override onSaveInstanceState in your activity A and store the value of your edit text as follows:

```
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

outState.putString(TEXT_VIEW_KEY, mTextView.getText());

// call superclass to save any view hierarchy
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
```

}

and in your onCreate activity should now check if there is any data that was previously saved and then initialize your textview

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// recovering the instance state
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    String text  = savedInstanceState.getString(TEXT_VIEW_KEY,);
}


setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

// initialize member TextView so we can manipulate it later
mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
mTextView.setText(text);
```

}

You may also want to check on architecture components for android specifically the life cycle aware components to easen your work nxt time

Answer (score 1):

This is not default behavior of Android.

Activity A will retain values until it is finished (destroyed). Check if you are not calling `finish()` after `startActivity()`.

Some solutions can be.

- Store your `EditText` value in [**SharedPreference**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).
- [**Save state**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-android-activity-state-using-save-instance-state) of `EditText` value

Answer (score 1):

check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886866/how-to-restore-values-of-a-activity-when-i-move-to-next-activity-and-come-back-a) you needn't saving your text in any way just put `finish()`
 in the end of second activity